# Static typing for function return value of nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, static-typing, mypy

I have a Python code:

```
from typing import List, Optional


class MyClass:
    pass


def generate_list() -> List[List[Optional[MyClass]]]:
    my_list = [[None for _ in range(10)] for _ in range(10)]
    # assignments might be extended in the future
    my_list[0][0] = MyClass()
    return my_list
```

I want generate list to return a list, that includes a list which might have either None or MyClass objects in it.
Simplified list might look like this

```
[[None, None, <my_class_object>], [<my_class_object>, None, <my_class_object>]]
```

Right now mypy is raising error on line

```
my_list[0][0] = MyClass()
```

With message

```
error: Incompatible return value type (got "List[List[None]]", expected "List[List[Optional[MyClass]]]")
```

I guess I'm missing something, or it even might not be possible to do what I want.

Comment: note that you can do `my_list = [[None]*10 for _ in range(10)]`

Comment: I actually could not reproduce the problem, so just guessing something other than your code playing role? Like Python version? Or not the same code.

Comment: @OndrejK I used Python 3.7 mypy in version, 0.610, unfortunately on Windows. It's not interpreter error but rather mypy static type checker error, it is also pointed out in PyCharm as type error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case where mypy's inference does not infer what you want. From the documentation:

> Mypy considers the initial assignment as the definition of a variable. If you do not explicitly specify the type of the variable, mypy infers the type based on the static type of the value expression

https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/type_inference_and_annotations.html

`my_list` is being inferred as `List[List[None]]` since that is the type of the expression. To fix this, you must annotate it as a `List[List[Optional[MyClass]]]`.

Comment: You are completely right. As my_list is defined it does not have any type assignes and list comprehension does create List[List[None]]. Change of the my_line assignment to:
`my_list: List[List[Optional[MyClass]]] = [[None for _ in range(10)] for _ in range(10)]` 
fixed the problem.